# resize UITableViewCell content

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Friends
I am working on `UITableView` where I want to dynamically resize `TableViewCell` on Button Click. But the problem is that I'm not getting how to calculate  and specify height for the cell at dynamically.I have tried but it will overlapped cell content. 
So please give me your suggestions..

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CACCustomCell * notesCell = (CACCustomCell *)[tableView1  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
    notesCell.buttonExpand.tag =  indexPath.row + indexpath.section;
    [notesCell.buttonExpand addTarget:self action:@selector(showDetails:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    if ([buttonExpandArray containsObject:indexPath])
    {
        UIFont *cellFont = notesCell.verifyLabel.font;
        CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(285.0f, MAXFLOAT);
        CGSize labelSize = [[verificationArray  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]  sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        CGRect frame = notesCell.verifyLabel.frame;
        frame.size = labelSize;
        frame.size.height =labelSize.height+30;
        notesCell.verifyLabel.frame = frame;
    }
    else
    {
        CGRect frame = notesCell.verifyLabel.frame;
        frame.size = CGSizeMake(285, 44);
        notesCell.verifyLabel.frame = frame;
    }
}
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:   (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([buttonExpandArray containsObject:indexPath])
    {
        CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(280.0f, MAXFLOAT);
        CGSize labelSize = [[verificationArray   objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]  sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Open Sans" size:14] constrainedToSize:constraintSize  lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        return labelSize.height + 140;
    }
    else
        return 44.0f;
}
```

[image: Here is the image of cell]

Comment: You want to implement accordion table view?

Comment: can you tell me in this screen shot any multiple lines?

Comment: No , I have added all this control on View

Comment: Is `buttonExpandArray` nil and does it contain any index path ?

Comment: yep it contains indexpath

Answer (score 1):

For variable height cells you need to implement tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: I once had a similar problem with cells not updating properly and in my (slightly different case) invoking setNeedsDisplay for the changed element in cellForRowAtIndexPath did the trick. Also: Are you sure that the cellForRowAtIndexPath method gets called to redo your cell after you collapse the cell?

Comment: Yes It's working properly when cell gets collapse. The main problem is after collapsing all cells it looks like all cell contents are mixed each other

Answer (score 0):

Add following method in code and return required height for givenindexpath, it will automatically resize the cell accordingly.

```
tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:
```

Comment: yes it will work but after cell collapse then it still shows whole content of the view

Comment: add one more line in cellForRowAtIndexpath as cell.clipsToBounds = true;

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     [tableView beginUpdates];
     [tableView endUpdates]; 
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  if([indexPath isEqual:[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]]) {
     return 100.0;
  }       
   return 50.0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`UITableView` has delegate method to set that, i.e. `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`..

If you ask for logical answer, I would say... Display you table as it is on view load.. take a flag which will check for button clicked in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` .. keep it to 0 on `viewDidLoad` and load table. change it on button click to 1 and reload table.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (buttonClickedFlag == YES) {
        return newHeight;
    } else {
        return regularHeight;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change hight based on content use this code

### (1) Create new Function copy below code

```
func calcheight(strin:String) -> CGFloat
    {
        let label =  UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.text = strin
        label.sizeToFit()
        return label.frame.height + 2

    }
```

(2) then copy this code put Contenct object in StringContent object

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    let height = self.calcheight(strin: StringContentObject)
    return height

}
```

this code don't need auto layout